# Can docker compose execute a command at stopping?

Tags: bash, systemd, docker-compose

Whenever a container is stopped, restarted or deleted, I would like it to execute a bash command for the host machine.

E.g. `fusermount -u /path/to/folder`

But I have not figured out a way to do this in the compose file. What I have in mind is similar to the `Exec STOP` function of systemd too.

Comment: Your Docker instance would have to be configured to detect and handle the `SIGTERM` signal.

Comment: @ceejayoz example compose file?

Comment: It wouldn't be something in the compose file. (You can configure the signal sent using `stop_signal`, and the length of time it's given to complete its shutdown tasks via `stop_grace_period`, but it's up to you and your application to decide what to do when the process receives a `SIGTERM`.)

Comment: (As an example, here's how Go handles signals: https://gobyexample.com/signals)